# Background script to detect which programs are launched

Tags: c++, windows-7

Basically I want to write a script to be able to detect when the user launches programs (on windows 7) in order to use the applications' icons to make MegaMan style splash screens.

I'm not really sure where to start. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook CreateProcess

some details here,  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11985/Hooking-the-native-API-and-controlling-process-cre

Or you could just keep watching all the processes and note the changes...